# Можно ли отправлять Ajax запрос используя относительный путь к файлу запроса?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Допустим есть файл ***file.js***, в нем выполняется запрос к файлу находящемуся в соседней папке от той, где находиться ***file.js***. Обязательно ли указывать полный путь `http://domen.com/dir/hendler.php`  или же все таки можно указать относительный путь?

Comment: можно указывать относительный - это не играет роли

Answer (score 1):

> или же все таки можно указать относительный путь?

Относительный путь указать можно, но не относительно js-файла, а относительно текущего url в браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, можно. Все правила при указании относительного пути выполняются.

Comment: Стоит несколько уточнить ответ.